# An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll, Additional information: Illegal characters in path

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am writing two functions:download and delete function for my gridview file 
so basically whenever the download button is click, it will check the field Games_RulesBooklet for the file name then download the file with the name locate inside "~/AppData/RulesData/". I'd successfully manipulate the attach function. But i can't seem to download the specific file i'd attach into RulesData

Whenever i try to download, errors pops up:

[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxGl8.png)
These line is in the cs file:

```
protected void DownloadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        string filePath = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument;
        Response.ContentType = ContentType;
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + Path.GetFileName(filePath)+ "\"");
        Response.WriteFile("~/AppData/RulesData" + filePath);
        Response.End();
}

protected void DeleteFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filePath = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument;
    File.Delete(filePath);
}
```

these lines are in my aspx file:

Download:

`<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" CommandArgument ='<#%      Eval("Game_RulesBooklet") %>' Text="Download" runat="server" OnClick ="DownloadFile"></asp:LinkButton>`

Delete:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID = "lnkDelete" Text = "Delete" CommandArgument  ='<#% Eval("Game_RulesBooklet") %>' runat = "server" OnClick = "DeleteFile" />
```

Comment: What is a typical example value that will be in `Game_RulesBooklet`?

Comment: 1.It's better to include errors in your question as html rather then refer to external image. 2.Just debug or output filePath to see what is in CommandArgument.

Comment: @rene, its either empty or the filename of the file i have attached inside /AppData/RulesData/

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim i use response.write for my filePath and got this:`<#% Eval("Game_RulesBooklet") %> `

Comment: It's your code, I am suggesting to see the actual value in debugger.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with the path where you are writing this response.
Please provide a path in the following format 
***Response.WriteFile("~\\AppData\\RulesData\\" + filePath);***

or you can even use **Server.MapPath**

Thevalue for filepath should not be empty , please add checks to avoid that.

Comment: I have tried changing the format to the one you suggested, but i still received the same error.

Comment: have you got the value of filepath from debugger ?

Comment: Expression: filePath Value=`<#% Eval("Game_RulesBooklet") %>`

Comment: Sorry but it is Null

Answer (score 0):

fix the code by shifting the hashtag
from this
`'<#% Eval("Game_RulesBooklet") %>'`
to this
`'<%#Eval("Game_RulesBooklet") %>'`